# Password validation in python with regex without duplicate chars

Tags: python, regex

The parameter is a string. Check whether it forms a secure password.
     A password is safe if

- there is at least a lowercase letter in it, and
- there is at least one capital letter in it, and
- there is at least one digit in it, and
- there is at least one special character (+, -, *, /,. or @) in it, and
- it counts at least 8 characters, and
- it has a maximum of 20 characters, and
- there are no three equal consecutive characters in it (eg 'a7XXX @ fda' is invalid because of the XXX), and
- no group of three characters occurs multiple times (eg 'XYZ.1a.XYZ' is invalid because XYZ appears twice).

I tried:

```
regex = [r'^.{8,20}$', r'[a-z]+', r'[A-Z]+', r'\d+', r'[-+*/.@]', r'(.)(.)(.)(\1\2\3)']

return all(re.search(pas, password) for pas in regex)
```

Comment: passwords of 100 chars are not safe?

Comment: What have you done to try to debug this? For example, have you examined each regular expressing individually to see which ones are failing? Also, what happens when you run your code? Do all passwords get marked as safe? unsafe? do you get an error?

Comment: I feel that iterating over the input would be much easier in your case

Comment: Please clarify the last condition. All other conditions are clear: `return re.search(r'^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=[^-+*/.@]*[-+*/.@])(?!.*(.)\1{2}).{8,20}$', s)`. Probably, you want an extra `(?!.*(...).*\2)` before `.{8,20}`. See [**this regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iErPv1/1).

Comment: I assume this is a homework assignment? If you're really trying to ensure "safe passwords", this is counterproductive. If it's homework, it helps to explain exactly what the assignment is. For example, are you actually required to use a series of regex matches for testing? If not, as GalAbra suggests, you probably don't want to use regex for at least some of them, but if it is required, such suggestions are wasting both your time and ours.

Comment: I think your core problem is that some of your patterns are written as positive matches and others are naturally written as negative matches, but you're treating them all as positive matches. For example, `'\d+'` says that there must be at least one digit, but `r'(.)(.)(.)(\1\2\3)'` says that there must be a repeated group of 3 characters, which is exactly the opposite of what you wanted to test.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I get errors while if i give passwords containing the three consecutive characters and with when they occur multiple times. so basically the last two points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lookahead assertions:

```
import re

reg=re.compile(r"(?=.*[a-z]+.*)(?=.*[A-Z]+.*)(?=.*\d+.*)(?=.*[-\+\*\./@]+.*)(?!.*(.)\1\1.*)(?!.*(.{3}).*\2.*).{8,20}$")

pwds=[ "aA3@5678", "aA3@567","abcdefghABCDEFGH+-*3","abcdefghABCDEFGH+-*3X","aA3@555678","aA3@@@5678", "a_A3Q_5678*A3Q", "a_A+Q_3.14/-5678*A+Q"]


for pwd in pwds:
    m=reg.fullmatch(pwd)
    print("{}: {}".format(pwd,"good" if m else "bad"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!